# Module parse failer due to an inappropriate loader when I'm trying to use optional chaining in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, babeljs, optional-chaining

I'm creating some new feature in an app that is built with Next. I need to use optional chaining in some of my logic. When I introduce optional chaining I get the following error.

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (371:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I searched the codebase and optional chaining is not used anywhere else.

Based on other suggestions, I've tried adding a Babel config as well as modifying the current Next config.

The current Next.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: "empty"
      };
    }
    return config;
  }
```

I tried modifying it to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Include Babel configuration for both client and server
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining']
        }
      }
    });

    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      };
    }

    return config;
  }
};
```

I installed the relevant dependencies but these additions just produced more errors.